# Vectorize nested for loops r

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization, named

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to vectorize a nested for loop in R.
Basically, the program looks up a particular coded value in a data frame, finds that code in a named list, and stores what the value codes to in a vector. At the end, I bind all those vectors together in order to create a matrix of uncoded values. I'm rather new to functional programming though, and would like to optimize this process somehow, but I can't quite figure out how to get this to work without the for loops!

**rawdata** is the coded values. Each column in rawdata is a question asked to survey takers. It looks like this:

```
q1 q2 q3
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 '' ''
```

**datacodes** is a data frame of lists of each question and their possible codes.

Notice that a3 is not in the list for q1. It happens that sometimes an answer is not in a codex, so I want to preserve the functionality where if a case like this occurs, the code is input, as opposed to an NA.
**l** is the list with each question being a named list of codes and answers. It is like **datacodes**, but is a list of named lists, so it looks like:

```
l = list(q1=list(a1=alpha,a2=beta), q2=list(b1=gamma,b2=delta)...)
```

and so on.
Here's the code:

```
#Checks each "cell" to see if the code is within the codex pertaining
# to the question asked, if it is, then the decoded value is stored
#if not, then the coded value is stored in the vector

for (column in 1:length(rawdata)){
  for (row in 1:length(rawdata$column1)){
    codex<-l[[colnames(rawdata)[i]]]
    code<-rawdata[[colnames(rawdata)[i]]][row]
    keys<-datacodes$data[[i]]$key
    if(code %in% keys){
      p[row]<-codex[[as.character(code)]]
    }
    else{
      p[row]<-code
      }
    }
  }
#tacks on each finished vector to form a matrix
decode<-cbind(decode,p)
}
```

The output should be something like:

```
q1    q2    q3
alpha gamma epsilon
beta  delta zeta
a3    ''    ''
```

Comment: If you can provide a sample of your data and your desire output, it would be easier to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution by removing the inter loop and using the `match` function.  This creates a copy of the original data and then substitute in the match values from the defined list, "l".  Since it is a named list, it is easy to retrieve the required value list for substitution.

```
rawdata<-read.table(header = TRUE, text="q1 q2 q3
a1 b2 c1
a2 b1 c2
a3 b1 ''")

l = list(q1=list(a1="alpha",a2="beta"), q2=list(b1="gamma",b2="delta"), q3=list(c1="epsilon",c2="zeta")) 

#make copy of data to update
answer<-rawdata

#loop through the question columns in rawdata
for (n in names(rawdata)) {
   #match the answer to the provide list
   mat<-match(rawdata[[n]], names(l[[n]]))

   #convert from factors to character type
   answer[[n]]<-as.character(answer[[n]])

   #Remove any NA answers and 
   #update the rows and column in the copy of the original data
   answer[[n]][which(!is.na(mat))]<- unlist(l[[n]][mat[!is.na(mat)]])
}
answer

     q1    q2      q3
1 alpha delta epsilon
2  beta gamma    zeta
3    a3 gamma
```

If depending on the number of answers compared to the number of questions with determine the degree of performance improvement.

Note: I did update your example data to improve testing.

Comment: This really helps! I was thinking using some sort of nested apply program, is there any reason why you wouldn't do that? Also, how exactly does this account for some answers given not being in l?

Comment: apply functions are just hidden loops, so it is best to use vectorized functions over apply.  For your second question, I start with a copy of the original data and then `which(!is.na(mat))` only updates the rows where there is a result from the list L.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly why it hasn't solved my problem. Basically, it works, but the last three rows of my data are not decoding, even though they are in the codex I'm looking at. Also, in random places things are not working.

Comment: @ThomasCampbell, I made a slight edit to the original post, please check to see that you are using the latest post.